# EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider + Bundling with wildcards

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, virtualpathprovider

I'm using the ([EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider) ) to allow views etc. to exist in a different DLL. I've got all this working nicely apart from the bunding, I've upgraded Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization to 1.1.2 which supports VPP but I can't get wildcards working.

e.g.
This works.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"));
```

This doesn't

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
```

I get an ArgumentException "Directory does not exist." with the following StackTrace

```
   at System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.Include(String virtualPath, IItemTransform[] transforms)
   at Shell.BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) in c:\dev\test\CIT\Shell\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs:line 24
   at CIT.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in c:\dev\test\CIT\CIT\Global.asax.cs:line 22
```

As far as I can see it's not going into the VPP code at all, it's obviously not the end of the world to fully specify the paths but I'd like to get this working if I can

Comment: Came across this question and I've run into the same issue. Luckily you saved me the time in figuring out it's because of the wildcard usage. Thanks!